# Linux MySQL - Can't login to root

Tags: mysql, linux

So I wrote this installer script for all my apps/settings on Ubuntu, which I used recently after upgrading to 16.04. One of the things it does is install mysql. I did it in a special way to kill those user prompts, because I don't want my script to stop for user input. Here is the code below:

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -qq -y mysql-server
```

Now, I try to sign into mysql from the terminal, but I can't. It's installed and running, but I keep getting access denied for the root user.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password
Enter password: 
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost''
```

I'm not entering any password, because I have not at any point in time setup a password.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: If you haven't set a password, why are you using `-p password` in your execution of `mysqladmin`?

Comment: Have you tried to run `mysql -u root`? If there is no root password that should work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to set a password for root:

For newer versions of MySQL (for MariaDB < 10.2 use the query at the bottom as it doesn't support alter user but still uses auth_socket)

> If you install 5.7 and don’t provide a password to the `root` user, it
>   will use the `auth_socket` plugin. That plugin doesn’t care and
>   doesn’t need a password. It just checks if the user is connecting
>   using a UNIX socket and then compares the username.

Taken from [Change User Password in MySQL 5.7 With "plugin: auth_socket"](https://dzone.com/articles/change-user-password-in-mysql-57-with-plugin-auth) and https://askubuntu.com/a/801950/395418

So in order to to change the `plugin` back to `mysql_native_password`:

1. Login with sudo:

   ```
   sudo mysql -u root
   ```
2. Change the `plugin` and set a password with a single command:

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'test';
   ```

Of course you can also use the command above to set an empty password.

Just for the record, there is also another way to only change the `plugin` without providing a password (leaving it empty):

```
    update mysql.user set plugin = 'mysql_native_password' where User='root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep I feel silly now. The issue was actually Linux permissions, not mysql. I installed it using sudo, I needed to login using sudo. No password needed, just sudo mysql -u root -p -h local host. Just press enter at the password prompt and viola, I'm in.

Thanks for the help.